# Why is “find -mtime +2” not showing files older than 48 hours

Tags: linux, unix, shell, shell-script, find

Any idea why `-mtime +2` didn't return test file. What I understand is +2 will return all file older than 48 Hrs.

```
$ pwd
/tmp/20122020
$ ls -rlt
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dmsjboss dmsjboss 0 Dec 17 21:34 test
$
$ date
Sun Dec 20 10:08:27 +04 2020
$
$ find . -name "test" -mtime +2
$
$
$
$ find . -name "test" -mtime +1
./test
$
```

Comment: The modification time of the file is `Dec 17 21:34 test`. So you would only get to see that file if you ran it at least after Dec 19 21:34` since `-mtime +2` means “Older than 48 hours” not simply what day it was. Unclear from your question when you actually ran the command, but that is the only explanation I can find for the `-mtime +1` working but `-mtime +2` not working.

Comment: @Giacomo1968  date output is present in my code . It was ran on "Sun Dec 20 10:08:27"

Comment: Odd. Might be related to timezone settings. Look at [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/207851) for more insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the file wasn't 3 days old when you ran the test, it was only two "full" days old.

```
man find
```

would have shown you

> File was last accessed less than, more than or exactly n*24
> hours ago.  When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago
> the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so
> to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least
> two days ago.

This is valid for mtime too

Comment: and `find -mtime 2` would have found it.